# change xilinx ise default text editor to notepad++

Tags: notepad++, xilinx-ise

I want to add custom editor to Xilinx ISE project nevigator.
How change xilinx ise default  text editor to notepad++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Windows version, in Xilinx ISE 14.7 under Edit > Preferences > ISE General > Editors, select the "Custom" editor and set the command line syntax to:

> notepad++ $1 -n$2

Then make sure that Notepad++ is listed in your Path environment variable. It's not there by default. To add it, go to My Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables and find the Path variable under the system variables. Add the directory that contains Notepad++ to the end of the list. It's likely "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++" if you used the default settings.

Comment: Thanks
I use "c:\\Program\file\(x86)\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe $1 -n$ -nosession"

Answer (score 0):

I'm using WinXP and entered the following command line syntax to use Notepad++ in read only mode (no quotes required):

> C:\\Progra~1\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe $1 -ro

Note: You must enter two backslashes due to how C++ works within Xilinx ISE.

Answer (score 0):

In additional, the path to Notepad++ folder must not contain any space characters. Alternatively, it must contain curly brackets, double back slashes or forward slashes in case that there are space characters in the path's name. Otherwise you will not open any file in ISIM because it does not have an option to set a custom text editor.

For example, the correct installation folder for Notepad++ are

```
{C:\Program Files(x86)\Notepad++\Notepad++.exe}

C:\\Program\ Files(x86)\\Notepad++\\Notepad++.exe

C:/Program\ Files(x86)/Notepad++/Notepad++.exe
```

But I prefer

```
C:/Notepad++/notepad++.exe
```

Also check [Xilinx answer record #13713](https://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/13713.html) to learn about command line syntax for Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Copy-paste below link it is working for me.

```
{C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe} $1
```